# Text templating engine/function in Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: vba, excel

A common usage of VBA at my company is generation of source code based on information entered in Excel tables.  Given VBA's native string manipulation, the code that does this is tedious to write and not very readable.

A simple example (these get more complex) is:

```
Print #fileIdentifier, SSpace(9) & "update_" & print_string & "[" & CStr(j) & "] <= 1'b0;"
Print #fileIdentifier, SSpace(9) & print_string & "_ack_meta" & "[" & CStr(j) & "] <= 1'b0;"
Print #fileIdentifier, SSpace(9) & print_string & "_ack_sync" & "[" & CStr(j) & "] <= 1'b0;"
```

I am looking for a solution in VBA that would allow me to specify this using a "text template", so define a text that would look something like this

> ```
>     update_@name@[@bit@] <= 1'b0;
>     @name@_ack_meta[@bit@] <= 1'b0;
>     @name@_ack_sync[@bit@] <= 1'b0;
> ```

and have a function/method call, passing the values of @name@ and @bit@, replace all instances of @name@ and @bit@ with corresponding values.

Comment: Store the template text in a file, load it and make replace$() calls?

Comment: What language are you generating code for?

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. for the suggestion.  There are hundreds of pieces of such code being filled in, so the text has to be stored inline.  I supposed manual calls to replace all the instances of the @label@ string would work, but it is still much more code than I am looking for, especially when the template text gets longer and contains many more 'variables' to replace.

Comment: Well you are always going to need to change the print statements to  accommodate anything new, your example could be re-factored to a single procedure taking a template string with ordinal insert markers: `update_@1@[@2@]\r\nXXX@3@` then a set of value variables

Comment: Store the "template" in a text file. Open it in VBA and perform the replacements based on the data stored in the Excel sheet.  Write it out to a new unique file.

Comment: @Blackhawk, please see my answer to AlexK - external files are not practical for hundreds of mini-templates.

Comment: @AlexK. A single procedure that does this is definitely something that would work, and I was hoping someone has already written something like that.  I do not know how in VBA to pass variable number of parameters, or ideally a dictionary/list of label-value pairs.  If you could provide an example I might be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic insertion function:

```
Function insert(template As String, ParamArray inserts() As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(inserts)
        template = Replace$(template, "%" & i + 1 & "%", inserts(i))
    Next

    '// some special cases perhaps
    template = Replace$(template, "%SSPACE%", SSpace(9))
    template = Replace$(template, "\r\n", VbCrLf)

    insert = template
End Function
```

For

```
?insert("Foo %1% Bar %2% Qux %3% (%1%)", "A", "B", "C")

Foo A Bar B Qux C (A)
```

**Map** (add a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*):

```
Dim col As New Scripting.Dictionary
col("name") = "bob"
col("age") = 35

MsgBox insert2("Hello %name% you are %age%", col)

...

Function insert2(template As String, map As Scripting.Dictionary) As String
    Dim name
    For Each name In map.Keys()
        template = Replace$(template, "%" & name & "%", map(name))
    Next
    insert2 = template
End Function
```

Comment: Thank You.  This works.  There are still few more tweaks before this becomes clean enough for what I ultimately want, but this definitely resolves my question.

Answer (score 2):

Alex K., thank you for the solution.

Here is how I expanded it (please feel free to let me know if there is a better way of doing this)

```
Function FillTemplateGeneric(template As Variant, map As Scripting.Dictionary) As String
    Dim name
    Dim out_text As String

    ' Handle multiple ways of receiving the template string
    If VarType(template) = vbString Then
        out_text = template
    ElseIf VarType(template) = vbArray Then
        out_text = Join(template, vbCrLf)
    ElseIf TypeName(template) = "String()" Then
        out_text = Join(template, vbCrLf)
    ElseIf TypeName(template) = "Variant()" And TypeName(template(LBound(template, 1))) = "String" Then
        out_text = Join(template, vbCrLf)
    Else
        MsgBox "Unknown Var Type passed to FillTemplateGeneric as first argument:" & vbCrLf & TypeName(template)
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "FillTemplateGeneric", "Unknown Var Type passed to FillTemplateGeneric as first argument:" & vbCrLf & TypeName(template)
    End If

    For Each name In map.Keys()
        out_text = Replace$(out_text, "%" & name & "%", map(name))
    Next
    FillTemplateGeneric = out_text
End Function
```

This allows for it to accept calls in multiple formats:

```
' Common dictionary for expansion
Dim col As New Scripting.Dictionary
col("name") = print_string

' Using inline text for template
MsgBox FillTemplateGeneric("test text with %name% name - just string", col)

' Using a multi-line string
Dim template As String
templ_text = "         update_%name% <= 1'b0; // 1 - manual multi-line string" & _
    vbCrLf & "         %name%_ack_meta <= 1'b0; // " & _
    vbCrLf & "         %name%_ack_sync <= 1'b0; // "
MsgBox FillTemplateGeneric(templ_text, col)

' Using an array of strings
Dim ttext(1 To 3) As String
ttext(1) = "         update_%name% <= 1'b0; // 2 - manual array of strings"
ttext(2) = "         %name%_ack_meta <= 1'b0; // "
ttext(3) = "         %name%_ack_sync <= 1'b0; // "
MsgBox FillTemplateGeneric(ttext, col)

' Using an inline array of strings 
MsgBox FillTemplateGeneric(Array( _
    "         update_%name% <= 1'b0; // 3 - immediate array of strings", _
    "         %name%_ack_meta <= 1'b0; // ", _
    "         %name%_ack_sync <= 1'b0; // " _
    ), col)
```

Comment: Nice.  You could tidy up the multiple line concats/ &_  by stuffing the logic in a class and having a series of `template.add "Line 1" ... template.add "line x"` calls.